# Cannot disable RC4

Tags: tls, apache-2.2

I'm trying to disable RC4 ciphers by using this configuration on apache:

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

But Qualys SSLTest is still saying that I'm using RC4, even though there is this `!RC4` flag.

I've tried this too:

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

I'm using Apache 2.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.1j

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

Changes:

1. `EECDH+aRSA+RC4` become `!EECDH+aRSA+RC4`
2. Remove `RC4`

Restart web server, clear cache in Qualys SSLTest.

Comment: This one worked, but there was another thing wrong, my virtual host configuration was overwriting apache configuration, I feel so stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first one includes RC4 as well as !RC4. It should contain !RC4 only.  The second one doesn't explicitly disable RC4 via a !RC4 parameter. Don't forget to restart apache after the configuration changes.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried with the !RC4 at the end of the second one and it didn't work either. Restarting apache and clearing the qualys ssl test cache.

Comment: The definition of !RC4 is to 'disable even when enabled elsewhere'. You are thinking of -RC4 which would mean it could be overruled somewhere else. The !RC4 should be enough therefore.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all RC4 references should be enough, so if you did that already, you should check if you're hitting the right virtual host.

Comment: Oh man, my virtual host configuration was overwriting my apache configuration, I feel so stupid